# How to create data in workspace

Tags: matlab

How to create the data like the picture as shown in below:

[image: m1 with 6x6 cell]

Figure 1: m1 with 6x6 cell

[image: After double click into m1, it shows the figure 2, assume all the zero in this picture is<code><6x63 cell></code>]

Figure 2: After double click into m1, it shows the figure 2, assume all the zero in this            picture is`<6x63 cell>`

[image: Double click m1{1,2} as shown in figure 3, each contains <code><4x4 double></code>]

Figure 3: Double click m1{1,2} as shown in figure 3, each contains `<4x4 double>`

[image]

I would like to place 0 into each `<4x4 double>` as shown in figure 4,any suggestion to create this data?

Answer (score 0):

How about reading some [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) first?

Also, [num2cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) can help. First you can construct a large matrix of zeros, in your case:

```
A = zeros([6,63,4])
```

Then you can change it into a cell array and only take the first 2 dimensions (figure 2)

```
C = num2cell(A,[1,2])
```

The last step is making figure 3, by replicating the matrix:

```
D = repmat(C,[6,6])
```

You then just remove the diagonal:

```
for ii = 1:6
    D(ii,ii) = 0
```

PS: code is untested